# automatic cap deploy on a successful Jenkins build

Tags: jenkins, capistrano

I would like Jenkins to perform

```
cap deploy
```

automatically on each successful build

has someone done this or has any ideas how that could be done?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Would https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Post+build+task do?

Answer (score 0):

After the build you can execute a shell script with any command you like, so I would put the cap command in there. Of course, Capistrano must be installed on the Jenkins system.

See the [Jenkins Wiki](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Building+a+software+project#Buildingasoftwareproject-ShellScriptsandWindowsBatchCommands) for further details about the Shell Scripts.

Comment: this shell script is executed as part of the build.
I would rather like this to be done as a post-build action because it is necessary just on successful builds.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to create separate project for deployment with 
Execute shell

```
cap deploy
```

and add it as "build other project" in the Post-Build Actions of the real project.

Comment: this works but from my point of view it isn't a very clean way to create a separate project for one simple command.

Comment: Can you setup capistrano to deploy files from jenkins workspace? Let's say during the build job some js files are compressed and I need to make a release starting from files that are created after build.